# createObjectURL is returning undefined in Chrome

Tags: javascript, file, video, upload

Trying to change video source file using createObjectDataURL. It is working fine with Firefox but not working in Chrome (version 12.0.742.122 m). code is not throwing any error but returns undefined for createObjectDataURL. I tried all the possibilities but it always returns undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Check CreateObjectURL</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

function ChangeProperty()
{
        var v = document.getElementById("myvideo");
        var file = document.getElementById("fileControl").files[0];
        v.setAttribute("src",window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
}
</script>
<body>
<div >
    <video id="myvideo" src="movie.ogg" controls ></video>
    <input type="file" id="fileControl" /> 
    <button id="btnprops" onClick="ChangeProperty()" >update</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me. It has already taken lot of time.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hey. I had the same problem, getting the error: 'Not able to load resource' while using window.URL.createObjectURL, though I have figured it out, that local resource won't load, however, if you host this HTML page on the Internet, then it would work smoothly, without any hassle

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485077/how-to-open-blob-url-on-chrome-ios  HTH

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, when I was opening the page as a local file in Chrome. I had to use Apache and open it through localhost.

Comment: I had to do the same but edit my hosts file to use a different hostname. For me Chrome still didn't like 'localhost'.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in Chromium, though the status of the bug is unclear to me: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91136

Crossposting my comment there:

> I can confirm this issue on Windows Chrome 17.0.932.0 dev-m. An easy way to confirm [the bug] is this page: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html. It works when used online. After saving to disk, the download fails.

Edit: Just found this similar bug report (FileReader API not working for local content): http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60889 This is marked `won't fix` for a reason that appears applicable to the bug discussed here.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  It semes that they have disallowed createObjectURL for file: resources due to security concerns, and they recommend either running a local HTTP server or using a Chrome app-bundle thing instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use window.webkitURL.createObjectURL() as noted in 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL

> Note: This method is prefixed in Chrome and Webkit as
>   window.webkitURL.createObjectURL().

Answer (score 0):

If you get stuck in this

```
  video.srcObject = mediaSource;
```

Use teh code above. Set the srcObject to your stream.