# createObjectURL doesnt work if run on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, websocket

Hello everyone,

I've tried to retrieve an image from a websocket server (in .NET)
I send the image as bytes then I retrieve it on the client side,
the code for retrieving on the client side (using canvas and JavaScript):

```
var c=document.GetElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ws.onmessage=function(evt)
{
    var image=new Image();
    image.src=URL.createObjectURL(evt.data);
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
}
```

it perfectly displays the picture on firefox,
but at Chrome, it just returning undefined and won't load the image through createObjectURL
I'm using Chrome 18.0.1025.162

any idea?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_(DOM)/window.URL.createObjectURL):

> This method is prefixed in Chrome and Webkit as `window.webkitURL.createObjectURL()`.

You should test if `URL` exists and then use the appropriate object:

```
(window.URL ? URL : webkitURL).createObjectURL(evt.data);
```

Comment: I wish I had seen this one earlier, made me lost around 10 hours working on my phone. Thanks !

Comment: When I try this, I still get a 404 not found for my blob, and get an additional `'webkitURL' is deprecated. Please use 'URL' instead.` - I believe the responses here explain the reason - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755401/createobjecturl-is-returning-undefined-in-chrome

Comment: @JonathanBasile My answer tested from `webkitURL` and used it (with `URL` as a fallback). I have just changed it to use `URL` by default and use `webkitURL` as a fallback. Does that work? If not, you may be using `createObjectURL` incorrectly (or in a way to violates some security assumption), and you should create a new question.

Comment: I think my problem is actually that I am testing on localhost - which apparently chrome forbids - I haven't tested it yet over the internet

Comment: A local server run on `localhost` *should* work (but maybe there's some kind of rule against it?). On the other hand, a `file:` URL may be likely to fail, as it does for many other new APIs, for security reasons.