# Angular : convert html table to doc

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

How can I convert a html table to document file?

Or

How can I convert an image (png), base64  or canvas (from html2canvas) to document file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

After converting to document, I want to download the file. I have already tried some library but no luck.

Comment: does this solve your problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330859/export-html-table-as-word-file-and-change-file-orientation

Comment: @FaizalHussain I need something written by typescript for angular client side

Comment: Did you tried this module? https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-export-as @Frost

Comment: I hope this link will clear your doubt. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330859/export-html-table-as-word-file-and-change-file-orientation

Comment: @Muthupriya i tried this, not working

Comment: @AnandSrivastava not working