# Chromium createObjectUrl from Image comes out as net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, chromium

I know that my code works because I have been using it in firefox. When I switched to chrome, this code snippet has stopped working due to chrome unable to read the url generated by `URL.createObjectURL()`.

```
export const image_preview = () => {
  $('.js-thumbnail').off()
  $('.js-thumbnail').on('change', function(event) {
    // add event to each file input
    const img = $(this).siblings('img')
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]) // url to user's image
    img.attr('src', url)
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url) // free the allocated object
  })
}
```

The url itself is generated but chromium fails to load it in my image tag.
[image: error]

Some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190647/createobjecturl-doesnt-work-if-run-on-chrome) suggests to use `webkitURL` api instead of `URL` but that didn't work either. Do you know the cause? Is this also a problem in other browsers as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait for the image has loaded before revoking its URL.

Image resources begin to load in a microtask after we set their `src` (among other reasons to allow setting `crossOrigin` properties after we set the `src`), so when the browser will read the `src` change, the line `URL.revokeObjectURL(url)` will already have been called, and the blob:// URL already pointing to nowhere.

So simply do

```
    const img = $(this).siblings('img')
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]) // url to user's image
    img.attr('src', url)
    img.one('load', (e) => { URL.revokeObjectURL(url); });
```