# JavaScript window.URL is undefined in function

Tags: javascript, html, video

I was learning some JavaScript, to select a file and use it to create an objectUrl which can be set as the `src` of an HTML5 `video`. I am trying this out in Chrome version 18.0.1025.162  on Ubuntu Lucid, and using a local HTML file with a JavaScript file and media files in the same folder.

I can select a video file using the input element and when I click on a play link, the JavaScript function `playVideo()` is executed.

```
<video id="vid" name='myvid' width="640" height="360" controls="controls">
       <source src="test.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
<br><a href="#" id="playlnk">Play </a> </li>
<br><input type="file" name="fileselect" id="fselect"> </input>
```

JavaScript file is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        player=$('#vid').get(0);        
        $('#playlink').click(function(){playVideo(player);});        
    });
function setVideoSrc(player,file){
    console.log('winurl='+window.URL);
    var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    player.src=fileURL;
    player.load();
    return;
}
function playVideo(player) {
     var file=document.getElementById('fselect').files[0];
     console.log('you chose:'+file);
     if (file==undefined){
        console.log('no file chosen');
     }else{
        console.log('file='+file);
        setVideoSrc(player,file);
     }     
}
```

When I don't select any file and click on the playlink, the default video plays and console log says no file chosen - as expected.

The error occurs when I select a video file and then click on the playlink. Then the `playVideo()` method calls `setVideoSrc()` in which the console log says `window.URL' is` undefined`

Why does this happen? Can someone help me correct this?
Here is the console log output

```
you chose:[object File] //from playVideo() function
file=[object File]   //from playVideo() function
winurl=undefined   //setVideoSrc() function
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createObjectURL' of undefined
```

Comment: [window.URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL) is Gecko-specific. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using ..chrome, is there a browser independent way to do this?

Comment: To my knowledge, there isn't (IE and Opera do not seem to support this at all). Chrome, however, has an equivalent (`window.webkitURL`) [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use window.webkitURL in Chrome.

This whould work in both Chrome and FireFox

```
function setVideoSrc(player,file){
    var myURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL
    console.log('winurl='+myURL);
    var fileURL = myURL.createObjectURL(file);
    player.src=fileURL;
    player.load();
    return;
}
```

See also:

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL
- http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#url

Comment: hi,that gives `file=[object File] winurl=[object DOMURL]` but then `fileURL=undefined`

Comment: I think this will work if chrome is started with file-access flag enabled

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:-

```
var file = document.getElementById('fselect').files[0];
if(file){
  setVideoSrc(player,file); 
}
```

Below line works on Chrome and Firefox:-

```
window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

Make sure, you are testing on mentioned browsers.

Refer to this information

- [window.URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL)
- [window.URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL)

Comment: I think it fails in chrome .Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755401/createobjecturl-is-returning-undefined-in-chrome

Comment: @damon: Which version of chrome are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
 window.location.href = "URL";
```

instead of window.url? Seems url isn't supported feature.

Comment: window.URL works with firefox..came across this post just now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755401/createobjecturl-is-returning-undefined-in-chrome

Comment: hm, then try to debug, what value is in window.url when method is executed

Comment: in console log window.URL prints the value `undefined`

Comment: but window.location is defined? what verison of chrome do you have?

Comment: I am using 18.0.1025.162 version.. yes window.location is defined

Comment: @damon it may be now, my response was 6 years ago.