# How to open Blob URL on Chrome iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

I'd like to open Blob object in a browser window.

This code works everywhere but iOS Chrome (and IE of course but I can solve IE). The window is not redirected to the url (which is correct or at least the same as in other browsers). Is there any known workaround for Chrome iOS?

```
var blob = new window.Blob(['Hello, world!'], {type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'});
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.location.href = url;
```

I've tried `<a href="{blobUrl}>` instead of `window.location.href` but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

FileReader solved my problem.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var out = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
reader.onload = function(e){
  window.location.href = reader.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(out);
```

Comment: For some reason, this works for PDF for me in Chrome IOS, but not for epub, where epub's application type is: blob = new Blob([oReq.response], {type: 'application/epub+zip'});  The code works for both types in Safari, just not chrome. :(

Comment: oh my... this part of my life is called Happiness

Comment: Hi all, I need to manage an archive file in Chrome IOS, is it possible? I tryied to create a blob like new Blob([........], {type: 'application/zip'}); but the code don't work.

Comment: is it possible to open file in new window for IOS ?

Answer (score 8):

[FileReader.readAsBinaryString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString) method has been deprecated.

Bit late, but I had todo something similar using the [FileReader.readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) - which produces a dataUrl. I'm using AngularJS $http service to call the API to create a pdf. Hope this helps, see below:

```
$http.post('/api/pdf', {id: '123'}, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
    .success(function (response) {
        var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
             $window.open(reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
```

Comment: Hi, Keano
Your solutions is working fine with Firefox, but when I tried with Chrome it doesn't seems to be working. It just shows the url but the pdf is not loaded. Can you please guide me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I use the FileReader.readAsDataURL with PDF stream fine with Firefox and Chrome. Since few days or weeks, users report me it does not work anymore with Chrome or Vivaldi (same engine) but still working on Firefox. Maybe a regression on Chromium ?

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me on Safari. I had to create a link on the page.

```js
const downloadBlob = (fileName, blob) => {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.target = '_blank';
  link.download = fileName;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
}

const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'video/mp4' });
downloadBlob('myfile.mp4', blob)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing content-type from application/json to application/octet-stream. My xlsx file was downloaded as json.

@PostMapping(value = "/export", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)