# How to display PDF (Blob) on iOS sent from my angularjs app

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, spring, pdf

My Angular 1.5 application connect to a Java/Tomcat/Spring backend server via REST.

One REST service generates PDF and send it to the client. It works fine on DEsktop browsers (FF, Chrome at least) but **I cannot see the PDF content on iOS (ipad for instance) whatever the browser I am using (Chrome, Safari..)**

Here is the Angular Code :

```
$http.get("/displayPdf", {responseType: 'arraybuffer', params: {id: 1}}).
 success(function(data) {
   var blob = new Blob([data], {type 'application/pdf'});
   var objectUrl =  window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   window.open(objectUrl);
 }
);
```

The Spring/Jax-RS code is :

```
@GET
@Path("displayPdf")
@Produces("application/pdf")
Response displayPdf(@QueryParam("id") Long id) {
  byte[] bytes = service.generatePdf(); 
  return javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ok().
    entity(bytes).
    header("Content-Type", "pdf").
    header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='test.pdf'").
    build();
}
```

I have done my research here for instance([AngularJS: Display blob (.pdf) in an angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app)) but could not find an appropriate solution.

So please, do you know what should I do to display the generated PDF to my iPad/iPhone end-users ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi!

You should visit that related post ;)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app

Comment: @fabien7474 did the answers resolved your issue ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

None of the solutions proposed above did work for me.

The main issue comes from `URL` that wasn't retrieved correctly in iOS. The following code do the correct work :

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
```

Also even with this, it did not work on Chrome iOS, neither Opera iOS...so after digging the internet and inspired with the following questions :

- [Blob createObjectURL download not working in Firefox (but works when debugging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694453/blob-createobjecturl-download-not-working-in-firefox-but-works-when-debugging)
- [How to open Blob URL on Chrome iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485077/how-to-open-blob-url-on-chrome-ios)
- [Display blob (.pdf) in an angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app)

... I finally ended up with the following code (working on all iOS browsers except FF on iOS) :

```
if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { //IE 11+
  window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "my.pdf");
} else if (userAgent.match('FxiOS')) { //FF iOS
  alert("Cannot display on FF iOS");
}
} else if (userAgent.match('CriOS')) { //Chrome iOS
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function () { $window.open(reader.result);};
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
} else if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) { //Safari & Opera iOS
  var url = $window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how can we make use of this in Angular?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below code as your `$http` call.I've handled for other browsers as well.

```
    $http.get("/displayPdf", {responseType: 'arraybuffer', params: {id: 1}}).success(function(data) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type 'application/pdf'});
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1||navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") != -1){
                    $window.open(URL.createObjectURL(file,{oneTimeOnly:true}));
    }else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPad") != -1){
                    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    //var anchor = document.createElement("a");
                    anchor.download="myPDF.pdf";
                    anchor.href = fileURL;
                    anchor.click();
    }else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1){
                        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                        anchor.href = url;
                        anchor.download = "myPDF.pdf";
                        document.body.appendChild(anchor);
                        anchor.click();
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            document.body.removeChild(anchor);
                            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
                        }, 1000);
      }
   });
```

Comment: This solution does not work for iPad. Still the same issue : nothing is displyaed

Comment: can you elaborate what issue you have faced while using this solution ? So that we can track what exactly happened as it is a tested out code.

Comment: Very simple : nothing happens on iPad whereas in Chrome for instance, Pdf is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

i use basically your same setup but i build my pdf differently using, unable to test with iOS but i hope this helps some

```
$http({ url: $scope.url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { 'Accept': 'application/pdf' },
            responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
        .then(function (response) {
            var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            $scope.pdfContent = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
        });//end http
```