# Downloading PDF as Blob not working on Chrome iOS

Tags: ios, angular, google-chrome, pdf-generation, chrome-ios

In my Angular 7 application, I have the following code for downloading PDF on various platforms.

```
this.http.get('/api/url', {responseType: 'blob'}).pipe(map(res => {
      return {
        filename: 'filename.pdf',
        data: res
      };
    }))
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          const fileBlob = new Blob([res.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});

          if (navigator && navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE10+
            navigator.msSaveBlob(fileBlob, res.filename);
          } else if (navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS')) { // iOS Chrome
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => {
              window.location.href = reader.result.toString();
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileBlob);
          } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) { // iOS Safari and Opera
            const url: string = URL.createObjectURL(fileBlob);
            window.location.href = url;
          } else {
            const url: string = URL.createObjectURL(fileBlob);
            const a: any = document.createElement('a');
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = res.filename;
            a.click();
            URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            a.remove();
          }
        }
      );
```

The download works fine on all platforms except Chrome iOS. I mainly followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375076/how-to-display-pdf-blob-on-ios-sent-from-my-angularjs-app#39545706) and a few other similar links.

I have also tried the following cases for Chrome iOS

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = () => {
    window.open(reader.result.toString());
};
reader.readAsDataURL(fileBlob);
```

Also replaced `onloadend` with `onload` above and tried both ways.
Plus I tried also with the code for `Safari`, but that failed as well.

Any idea what I maybe missing here?

Answer (score -2):

removing the custom chrome ios check worked for me:

```
        ...subscribe(response => {
            const file = new Blob([response.body], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            const fileURL = (window.URL || window['webkitURL']).createObjectURL(file);
            const fileName = 'Whatever.pdf';

            const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            downloadLink.href = fileURL;
            downloadLink.download = fileName;
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
            document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
        })
```